# $p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}}$ has at least one strictly positive eigenvalue.

Tags: vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> let $(E,\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle)$ an euclidean vector space with $\dim(E)=2n$. Let F and G two non-orthogonal linear subspaces of E with $\dim(F)=\dim(G)=n$. Let $p_{_{F}}$ be the orthogonal projection on F and $p_{_{G}}$ be the orthogonal projection on G. Prove that $p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}}$ has at least one strictly positive eigenvalue.

The characteristic polynomial of $p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}}$ and $p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}}$ are the same since $p_{_{G}}^2 = p_{_{G}}$.

Since $p_{_{G}}$ and $p_{_{F}}$ are orthogonal projections, they are self-ajoint operators.                     Let $(x,y)\in E^2$
$$
\langle (p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}})(x) ,y\rangle = \langle ( p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}})(x) ,p_{_{G}}(y)\rangle = \langle p_{_{G}}(x) ,(p_{_{F}} \circ p_{_{G}})(y)\rangle = \langle x ,(p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}} \circ p_{_{G}})(y)\rangle$$
So $p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}} \circ p_{_{G}}$ is a self-ajoint operator

Ad absurdum, let's suppose that $p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}} \circ p_{_{G}}$ has only negative eigenvalues, ie $-(p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}} \circ p_{_{G}})$ is a positive self-adjoint operator ie $\forall x \in E, \langle -(p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}})(x) ,x\rangle \geq 0$

if $ F \cap G \neq \lbrace{0}\rbrace$  , let  $x\in  (F \cap G)\setminus \lbrace{0}\rbrace$
$$\langle -(p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}})(x) ,x\rangle = -\langle x,x \rangle < 0$$
hence the contradiction because $-(p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}} \circ p_{_{G}})$ is a  positive self-adjoint operator

I could not find the case where $ F \cap G = \lbrace{0}\rbrace$

Answer (score 1):

Since F and G are non-orthogonal, there is $g_0 \in G \setminus F^\perp$
$$\langle (p_{_{G}} \circ p_{_{F}}\circ p_{_{G}})(g_0) ,g_0\rangle = \langle (p_{_{G}}( p_{_{F}}(p_{_{G}}(g_0) ),g_0\rangle = \langle (p_{_{F}}(p_{_{G}}(g_0) ),p_{_{G}}(g_0)\rangle \:\:\text{($p_{_{G}}$ is self-adjoint)}$$
$$=\langle (p_{_{F}}(p_{_{G}}(g_0) ),p_{_{F}}(p_{_{G}}(g_0))\rangle \:\:\text{($p_{_{F}}$ is an orthogonal projection)}$$
$$ = \langle (p_{_{F}}(g_0),p_{_{F}}(g_0)\rangle > 0 \: because \: g_0 \notin F^\perp $$
hence the contradiction